# javascript to check if user has inputted

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a form

```
<form method="post" action="sendmail.php" name="Email form">

Message ID 
<input type="text" name="message_id" /><br/><br/>

Aggressive conduct 
<input type="radio" name="conduct" value="aggressive contact" /><br/><br/>

Offensive conduct 
<input type="radio" name="conduct" value="offensive conduct" /><br/><br/>

Rasical conduct 
<input type="radio" name="conduct" value="Rasical conduct" /><br/><br/>

Intimidating conduct 
<input type="radio" name="conduct" value="intimidating conduct" /><br/><br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Mail" />
</form>
```

I need some sort of validation javascript that:

1. Checks if user entered a message id and checked one of the radio buttons. (So message id and radio group are required fields)
2. Display an error message if any of the required fields is not set.
3. Block form submit until required fields are entered.

Can anyone help?

Comment: When do you want to check this?

Comment: This would require an huge answer. Why don't you follow some online tutorials for validation? And also remember to check on the server side, in case someone disabled JavaScript.

Comment: Try something by yourself, if you bump into trouble ask for help with your existing code.. [good starting point](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/javascript/form_validation.php) - just one of the top results from Google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do a validation before submit.

Add an on submit event handler (that will be called when the form is submitted) to the form:

You can do this in two ways:

```
<form method="post" action="sendmail.php" name="Email form" onsubmit=validate()>
```

OR

in the `<script>` part:

```
window.onload = init;

function init()
    {
         document.forms["Email form"].onsubmit = function() 
                                                           { 
                                                               validate(); 
                                                               return false; 
                                                           };
    }
```

Now write the validate function itself (same for both options above):

```
function validate()
{
    var form = document.forms["Email form"]; //Try avoiding space in form name.
    if(form.elements["message_id"].value == "") //No value in the "message_id" box
    {
        alert("Enter Message Id");
        //Alert is not a very good idea. 
        //You may want to add a span per element for the error message
        //An div/span at the form level to populate the error message is also ok
        //Populate this div or span with the error message
        //document.getElementById("errorDivId").innerHTML = "No message id";

        return false;  //There is an error. Don't proceed with form submission.

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use the `onclick` event for the validation. What if the person hits enter? That will submit the form, without clicking the submit button. Use `<form ... onsubmit="validate">` instead.

Comment: @Austin Hyde valid point. Updated answer

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker that's why option 2.

Comment: IIRC, `document.forms[]` only works with form `id`s, not form `name`s. I may be wrong though, as it's been a while since I used that particular feature.

Comment: @Austin, document.forms[] does work for names. Actually it does not work for ids (Non IE. IE uses them interchangeably. An element can be accessed by name as its id.)

Comment: @Nivas: Yep, sorry, I was hasty on my (now removed) comment.

Comment: @Nivas - [It appears Mozilla *does* use `id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.forms)

Comment: @Nivas i cant get your code working for me :/ i entered everything you put and tested and it just carrys on as normal e.g submitting empty inputs

Comment: @Louismoore18,  updated. This works for me. Can you try?

Comment: @Austin Hyde, the lonk you posted does not say anything about id or name. In `document.forms[2]`, 2 is the index of the forms array.

Comment: @Nivas, this is why I need to drink coffee in the morning :D I'll concede my point.

Comment: @Nivas it still doesnt work for me. Ive copied exactly what you wrote? In the bottom left of page it says error on page if that means anything?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**. Now it should work.

```
// Register onsubmit callback function (this will be called when the user submit his data).
document.forms[0].onsubmit = validate;

function validate() {
   var message = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value,
       radioButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
       oneRadioChecked = false;

   //  check that message is not empty
   if (message.length  === 0) {
      alert("no message inserted");
      return false;
   }

   // check that at least one radio has been checked 
   for (var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length && !oneRadioChecked; i++) {
      oneRadioChecked = (radioButtons[i].type === "radio" &&radioButtons[i].checked);
   }

   if (!oneRadioChecked) {
      alert("no radio button checked");
      return false;
   } 
}
```

Comment: @user278044 i couldnt get this to work for me